# View didn't return a response

Tags: django

I am working on a python django web app in which I want to implement internationalization and auto translate the whole app into french or chinese.

I took reference from this site https://www.metod.io/en/blog/2015/05/05/django-i18n-part-1/

But whenever I try to run the app it shows this error:

> 500: ValueError at /en/get_dashboard_data/ The view
>   dashboard.views.getDashboardData didn't return an HttpResponse object.
>   It returned None instead.

And url get_dashboard_data is fetching data through ajax.

```
url(r'^get_dashboard_data/$', views.getDashboardData, name='getDashboardData'),
```

view

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def getDashboardData(request):
    dbname = request.user.username
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        if request.POST.get('action') == 'sale_chart_data':
            data = DashboardData(dbname).getSaleChartData()
            channel_list = data[0]
            data_list = data[1]
            print 123, data_list, channel_list
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'channel_list':channel_list, 'data_list':data_list}), content_type='application/json')

        if request.POST.get('action') == 'get_sale_numbers':
            sale_data = DashboardData(dbname).getSaleNumbers()
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'sale_number_data':sale_data}), content_type='application/json')

        if request.POST.get('action') == 'get_inventory_numbers':
            inventory_data = DashboardData(dbname).getInventoryData()
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'inventory_data':inventory_data}), content_type='application/json')

        if request.POST.get('action') == 'get_order_numbers':
            order_data = DashboardData(dbname).getOrderData()
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'order_data':order_data}), content_type='application/json')

        if request.POST.get('action') == 'get_hourly_data':
            order_data = DashboardData(dbname).getHourlyData()
            sale_data = order_data[1]
            count_data = order_data[0]
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'sale_data':sale_data, 'count_data':count_data}), content_type='application/json')

        if request.POST.get('action') == 'top_performers':
            data = DashboardData(dbname).getTopPerformers()
            inventory_count_dict = data[0]
            current_month_dict = data[1]
            last_month_dict = data[2]
            current_quarter_dict = data[3]
            current_year_dict = data[4]
            channel_list = data[5]
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'inventory_count_dict':inventory_count_dict,'current_month_dict':current_month_dict,'last_month_dict':last_month_dict,'current_quarter_dict':current_quarter_dict,'current_year_dict':current_year_dict,'channel_list':channel_list}), content_type='application/json')

        if request.POST.get('action') == 'top_products':
            product_data = DashboardData(dbname).getTopProducts()
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'product_data':product_data}), content_type='application/json')
```

javascript

```
function getSaleChart(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "/get_dashboard_data/",
        type : "POST",
        data : {action:'sale_chart_data'},

        success : function(response) {
            channel_list = response.channel_list;
            data_list = response.data_list;
            c3.generate({
                bindto: '#sale-chart-30-days',
                data:{
                    x: 'dates',
                    xFormat: '%b %d',
                    columns: data_list,
                    colors:{
                        Flipkart: '#1AB394',
                        Paytm: '#BABABA'
                    },
                    type: 'bar',
                    groups: [ channel_list ]
                },
                axis: {
                    x: {
                        type: 'timeseries'
                    }
                }
            });
        },

        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            toastr["error"]("Something Broke.", "Oops !!!.");
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with any of the code you've shown here, you should show your  view. Or just look at it. make sure *every* path in that view returns a response.

Comment: @Sayse actually if I don't include i18n package, then the app is working perfectly fine and returning response too but when I added the i18n package it is showing that error

Comment: It would be working fine because whatever change you made makes the view take a different route through the views logic.

Comment: Oh okay but I am unable to figure out the url pattern as it is automatically appending /en/ in each url

Comment: The url routing is working correctly which is why you get to this error, you should show the view..

Comment: views.py added to the question

Comment: Either the request method isn't post, it isn't an ajax request, or the action isn't one of the given types

Comment: The request method is post and the action type is also correct. If you want, the I can show you my js file in which I am making ajax request

Comment: As you are already using `print` statements, add `print request.method, request.is_ajax(), request.POST` to the beginning of your view to figure out what is going on. Alternatively, launch a debugger with `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

Comment: yeah tried it but its not working

Answer (score 3):

This is why you should really practice more defensive programming. Though you insist that the request method is POST and it is ajax and the action is sale_chart_data one of the three isn't what you expect it to be.

Your function really should be like follows. It's plain old good practice.

```
def getDashboardData(request):
    dbname = request.user.username
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        action = request.POST.get('action') 
        if action == 'sale_chart_data':
            data = DashboardData(dbname).getSaleChartData()
            ....
        ... 
        # other if conditions here
        else :
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message':'Unknown action {0}'.format(action)}), content_type='application/json')

    else :
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message':'Only ajax post supported'}), content_type='application/json')
```

And then you ought to set break points and evaluate the request to figure out what exactly is happening in this particular request.

Comment: Instead of a plain HttpResponse, I would recommend returning a [HttpResponseBadRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseBadRequest) for, well, bad requests.

Comment: @DanielHepper right you are. if we wanted to dig really deep, we could replace HttpResponse with JsonResponse as well.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your JavaScript does indeed make a POST request to `/get_dashboard_data/` but it receives a redirect response (HTTP 301 or 302) to `/en/get_dashboard_data/` due to some kind of i18n middleware.

The browser follows the redirect, but the new request to `/en/get_dashboard_data/` is a GET request.

Edit:

When following a redirect, the browser will always perform the second request as GET, there is no way to prevent that. You have several options to solve this:

- make the initial request to the right application. This means you have to pass your i18n URL into your JavaScript instead of hardcoding it. You can add something like this to your template:

  `<script>var dashBoardDataUrl = "{% url "name-of-dashboard-url" %}"</script>`
- as your "actions" just get code, you could just accept a GET request and read the action from query paramters
- Split that view into several smaller views that accept GET request so you have something that resembles a REST API.

Comment: Yeah u r right the new request is a GET request. Can u plz suggest how to resolve this issue?